# Ruby Multi Process Postgres Connections

Tags: ruby, postgresql, connection-pooling

I'm thinking about a process infrastructure where a lot of worker processes will be spawned from one master process. Each worker will execute one long running task and will be killed after he finishes his task. In 24h there will be about 100000 Tasks. This won't be a problem until I need to write the result of the tasks into a postgres database, because this would lead to 100000 single Database Connections a day.

So my question is: Is there a way to handle something like a connection pool in the master process and hand over the connection to the child process? And will it be possible, that the child won't close the connection until it finishes (because the owner of the process is the master process)

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL has at least two commonly used connection poolers:

pgbouncer - https://pgbouncer.github.io/features.html

and

pgpool - http://www.pgpool.net/mediawiki/index.php/Documentation

Both of which have their own feature sets. Evaluate both and see which would be most suited to you. For example you may want to use transaction pooling of pgbouncer so you only spawn a connection whilst one of the child workers are processing. Once this process is complete it will release the connection back into the pool. It sounds like you will need multiple connection pools to handle that amount of concurrency.